# jquery create nested object by adding properties in each - Error Uncaught TypeError: .....of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I got a code

```
var dash = {};

function saveResults() {
    var sectName = 'Answers';

    if(!dash.hasOwnProperty(sectName)) {
      dash[sectName] = {}
    }

    $('.selected').each(function () {
        sectName = $(this).closest('.question-wrapper').data('group');

        var question = $(this).closest('.question-wrapper').find('.question span').text().trim().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');

       dash[sectName][question] = $(this).val();
    });
}
```

I want to create a nested object with section name and question name with answers inside. But code gives

```
main.js:373 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'QuestionText' of undefined
```

Comment: most probably you may be getting sectName as undefined. please console.log  the value and check, or use a debugger

Comment: check this in your browser console. You will get the same error while excecuting dash[undefined]['QuestionText'] = 1..Issue may be with sectName = $(this).closest('.question-wrapper').data('group');, without seeing your html its difficult to predict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what structire you want your Answers and Questions to have. But your `if` block should be in the loop block to work properly.

```
var dash = {};

function saveResults() {
  var sectName = 'Answers';

  $('.selected').each(function () {
    sectName = $(this).closest('.question-wrapper').data('group');

    if(!dash.hasOwnProperty(sectName)) {
      dash[sectName] = {}  
      var question = $(this)
                     .closest('.question-wrapper')
                     .find('.question span')
                     .text().trim().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
      dash[sectName][question] = $(this).val();
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: this works. thanks. I just thought that dash[sectName] = {} for new section would clear current object and make it empty one. But this works! Thank you.